# not able to upload and save files from my up to Heroku Server

Tags: heroku, carrierwave

I am trying to upload an image through the wen interface. I am using CarrierWave. It works just fine on my local window machine. 
On heroku i get the following errore message: 
Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /app/bboads/tmp):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to upload the picture to your `public/` folder. Heroku doesn't let you do this. You need to create a bucket on Amazon's S3 service and upload to that.

[Here is a similar q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546206/how-to-upload-images-on-heroku-server-using-attachment-fu-plugin)

Comment: That is what i am trying to do. Thanks you so much. So there is no way of uploading files to Heroku?

Comment: no, you cannot upload to heroku's server. You have to use Amazon or another storage service. If you need more info just google it or post a comment and I can give you a link.

Comment: yes you can do it. you need to add 'def cache_dir' per the current carrierwave readme, or described here http://pardner.com/2012/01/rails-3-1-carrierwave-s3-heroku/